# how to find a function expression of a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the following power series: $x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$.

I want to use the sum of the geometric series $\sum^\infty_\limits{k=0}{x^k}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to write a function $f(x)$ for the power series above.

When I look at the series I see that its equal to $\sum^\infty_\limits{k=0}{\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}}$, which is the integral of the geometric power series.

$$\int{\sum^\infty_{k=0}{x^k}=\int\frac{1}{1-x}}\implies \sum^\infty_{k=0}{\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}}=-\ln|1-x|$$

The function expression should be $f(x)=-\ln|1-x|$.

Is it correct to do it this way? Am I missing constant values after integrating?

Comment: I'm trying to relate this to the geometric series

Comment: If you plug $0$ in the initial power series, you should get the same value with the analytical function.

Comment: So is this correct? does f(x) equal to the series for all x?

Comment: I haven't looked at your calculations, but yes, differentiating and antidifferentiating are common ways of trying to find closed forms for power seies.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that f(x) is the correct function for the series ?

Comment: If you write down the Taylor series of $f$, you should get your original series.

Comment: "Does $f(x)$ equal to the series for all $x$?" No. The series does not converge everywhere, only for $|x|<1$.

Comment: So am i to understand now that for $|x|\le1$ both f(x) and the series are converge and are equal?

Comment: Can't use $x=1$ otherwise get $-\ln(0)$.

Comment: Finally, $ f(x)=-\ln(1-x)$ equals the series for $-1 \le x < 1$. For other values of $x$, the series diverges.